# Rendering a react app with data from nodejs server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm new to react and am wondering what the best practice is for serving a react page from node.js.

I am trying to create a weather app.  The app should render a page.  The user inputs information then sends a post request the node.js/express server.  The server should make an API call and store the data as a JSON and then send the data back to the react page as a result.

I have done this with ejs but I can't figure out how to do easily with React as a view engine in express.

Here is my express server file.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const https = require("https");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req,res) {
    res.render("main", {
      realTemp: null
    });
});

app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  const query = req.body.city;
  const apiKey = "a valid api key";
  const unit = "imperial";
  const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=" + apiKey + "&q=" + query + "&units=" + unit;

https.get(url, (response) => {
  console.log("statusCode", res.statusCode);

  response.on("data", (d) => {
    const weatherData = (JSON.parse(d));
    console.log(weatherData);
    res.render("main", {
      realTemp: weatherData.main.temp
    });
  });
}).on("error", (e) => {
  console.error(e);
})
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Here is my main ejs page:

```
<%- include("header") -%>

<br>
<form action="/" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="city" />
  <br>
  <input type="submit">

</form>
<br>
<h1>
    Results:
</h1>

<p>
    <%= realTemp %>
</p>


<%- include("footer") -%>
```

Any advice would be welcome.

I also won't be able to reply until I get 15 reputation.
Thanks!

Edit/followup:
I'm getting close but can't get my front end to work yet.

Here is my file structure:
[screenshot of file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZSAU.png)

index.html-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>React App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    <script src="../src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.js-

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

src/components/App.jsx-

```
import React, { useState } from "react";


function App() {

  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState({})
  console.log(weatherData);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(
        "http://localhost/:5000",
      );
      const data = await result.json()

      setWeatherData(data);
    };

    fetchData();
  })

  return (
    <div>
     <h1>The temprature is {weatherData.main.temp}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

server.js-

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'jsx')

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  const query = req.body.city;


  const apiKey = "a valid key";
  const unit = "imperial";
  const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=" + apiKey + "&q=" + query + "&units=" + unit;


  https.get(url, (response) => {
    console.log("statusCode", res.statusCode);

    response.on("data", (d) => {
      const weatherData = (JSON.parse(d));
      console.log(weatherData);
      res.send(weatherData);

    });
  }).on("error", (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  })
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

package.json-

```
{
  "name": "weather4",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start | nodemon server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Here is the error I get when I run 'npm start'
[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yx8Dr.png)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

In your  server, you should create a get API for your client to get weather data. Then, in your React app, use fetch [read about fetch here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to get data from your server. Something like this: 
In your server:

```js
...

app.get("/", function(req,res) {
    const query = req.body.city;
    const apiKey = "a valid api key";
    const unit = "imperial";
    const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=" + apiKey + "&q=" + query + "&units=" + unit;

  https.get(url, (response) => {
    console.log("statusCode", res.statusCode);

    response.on("data", (d) => {
      const weatherData = (JSON.parse(d));
      console.log(weatherData);
      res.send(weatherData)
    });
  }).on("error", (e) => {
    console.error(e);
  })
});

...
```

In you React app:

```js
import React from 'react'
...
const YOurComponent = () => {
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = React.useState({})
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(
        'your server url',
      );
      const data = await result.json()
      
      setWeatherData(data);
    };
 
    fetchData();
  })

  return (
    <div>{weatherData.main.temp}</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using create-react-app you should be building the react-app separately and static serving the generated build directory inside your express server.

```
// client is the directory where all your client-side react code lives

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
  });
}
```